# Form Posts Every Time Page Reloads

Tags: php, forms

Can someone help me out as i'm quite new to coding.

I'm using smarty template engine and i have this form that is for users to update they're cover image or add one but my problem is that every time i or a user reloads the page the form posts a new image everytime without even pressing submit button.

Here is the form.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="cover_upload">
    <input type="file" name="cover_file" id="file" class="cover_input" />           
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="change_cover" />
    <a class="submit_form_button" style="float:right" onclick="jQuery('#cover_upload').submit();" href="javascript:void(0);">Change</a>
</form>
```

And here is the php

```
if (isset($action) && $action=='change_cover' && isset($_SESSION['loggeduser_id'])){
    if (isset($_FILES['cover_file']['name']) && $_FILES['cover_file']['name']){
        if (($_FILES["cover_file"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["cover_file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["cover_file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") || ($_FILES["cover_file"]["type"] == "image/png")){
            $filename = $_SESSION['loggeduser_id']."_".date("YmdHis").".jpg";
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["cover_file"]["tmp_name"],"$basepath/thumbs/users/covers/" . $filename)){
                $user = new User();
                $user->update($_SESSION['loggeduser_id'],array("cover" => $filename));
                $_SESSION['loggeduser_details']['cover'] = $filename;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone please show or tell me what is going on and how to fix this thanks

Comment: Can't help you based on what you've posted, which won't reproduce the problem. You need to try to produce a minimal example which actually reproduces your problem; you'll probably figure out what the problem is in doing so. If you don't, post what you come up with.

Comment: My problem is every time i or a user reloads the page the form posts a new image everytime without even pressing submit button

Comment: I know, you said that. I'm telling you, we cannot guess what the problem might be based on what little code you've provided.

Comment: It's normal when a form has posted once, you click on reload button, it's reposted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're not following the [POST/REDIRECT/GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern. If a POST request is successful, you should ALWAYS redirect.

Example:

```
$success = $obj->doSomething($_POST['var']);

if($success){
    header('Location: page.php?m=success');
    exit;
} else{
    //Something went wrong...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are pressing f5 key (or click reload button) after submitting the form it will re submit the form.. In chrome you will get a confirming message..

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out this, without requiring redirect technique, as the modern AJAX JavaScript permits:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(".submit_form_button").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "",
      data: $("#cover_upload").serialize(),
      success: function () {
        //alert("OK");
      }
    });
    //
    // this is important not to trigger the link action:
    //
    return false;
  });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<?php
//
//...
//
if (isset($action) && $action=='change_cover' && isset($_SESSION['loggeduser_id'])){
    if (isset($_FILES['cover_file']['name']) && $_FILES['cover_file']['name']){
        if (($_FILES["cover_file"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["cover_file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["cover_file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") || ($_FILES["cover_file"]["type"] == "image/png")){
            $filename = $_SESSION['loggeduser_id']."_".date("YmdHis").".jpg";
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["cover_file"]["tmp_name"],"$basepath/thumbs/users/covers/" . $filename)){
                $user = new User();
                $user->update($_SESSION['loggeduser_id'],array("cover" => $filename));
                $_SESSION['loggeduser_details']['cover'] = $filename;
            }
        }
    }
}
//
//...
//
?>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="cover_upload">
    <input type="file" name="cover_file" id="file" class="cover_input" />           
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="change_cover" />
    <a class="submit_form_button" style="float:right" href="">Change</a>
</form>  

<?php
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I've modified these items:

1. Suppressed onclick event handling of the .submit_form_button link to use jQuery click event assignment.
2. Reload-safe: by adding jQuery.ajax() to post the form. So no Form.submit() is used, it will not repost if the user press the [RELOAD] button.